# Updating to TFS2017 BugWorkItems

Tags: tfs

After updating to TFS I tried to configure new features and I get the following error message:

> [Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: BugWorkItems/BugWorkItems. TF400506: This element defines the states for work items that represent Bugs or Defects. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types that are defined in: BugWorkItems. The following states do not exist in any of the work item types: Approved, Committed.

I read all about updating WIT and what not on the MSDN page but it is not the easiest way to go about.

Can someone help me out and point me into a direction on what I have to do?

Comment: Which process template (like like Agile) and which TFS version?

Comment: Have you tried running the "Enable Features" option from the web portal?

Comment: What have you customized for your Bug work item around states and transitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TF400654 error means a mapping defined in the ProcessConfiguration file specifies a field or state that does not exist in the WIT defined for the team project.

You can either download the process template, modify the ProcessConfiguration file to correct the mapping, and then upload the process template, or export the WIT using `witadmin exportwitd`, add the missing field or state, and then import the WIT. Get more information from following links:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/customize-agile-tools
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx

Comment: Thanks with your hints I got it to work. It was a pain but its up to date now and works fine :-)

Comment: @Matteo Do you mind sharing more details on how fixed it?